# How does one change the git config core.autocrlf from true to input?

Tags: git

I have tried using the command `git config core.autocrlf input` and it returns a `fatal: not in a git directory` error message. I have also used the command `git config --global core.autocrlf input` which does change it in the global directory, however this does not help me because still in my projects, it takes from the `git config --list` and not the `git config --global --list`.

Comment: Run `git config core.autocrlf input` or `git config --local --remove core.autocrlf` in your projects?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is giving you a big hint: you need to run that command *in each individual git working copy*. Local configuration takes precedence over global configuration, and "local" means "stored in the git database of a working copy".

Comment: You mean "in the git repository", or something like that—the word `checkout` kind of implies the current commit though, so it's definitely not the right word here.

Comment: @torek I was trying to avoid "repository" because new users often don't have a strong intuition about every clone being its own repository, but you're right, "checkout" wasn't the best choice. I've edited to "working copy", which is hopefully a better compromise?

Comment: Yes, that's probably a good choice.